# How to fix undefined method error with nested resources in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources

I get an error saying "undefined method `verses' for nil:NilClass" when I visit

```
/books/1/chapters/1/verses/new
```

My routes.rb:

```
resources :books do
  resources :chapters do
    resources :verses
  end
end
```

verse_controller.rb:

```
class VersesController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :find_book
    before_filter :find_chapter, :only => [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def new
        @verse = @chapter.verses.build
    end


    private
    def find_book
        @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
    end

    def find_chapter
        @chapter = Chapter.find(params[:chapter_id])
    end

end
```

Any adviceo on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at your before_filter

```
before_filter :find_chapter, :only => [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Now you hit `new`, but there is no `before_filter` triggered for `new`, so `@chapter` is nil.

Solution: Add `:new` to the only array.

**Update** The way you get ids using params is not correct, params is for query string or POST. You need a bit extra effort to get params from path.

```
before_filter: get_resources # Replace your two filters

private
def get_resources
  book_id, chapter_id = request.path.split('/')[1, 3]
  @book    = Book.find(book_id)
  @chapter = Chapter.find(chapter_id)
end
```

Comment: When I have puts params[:chapter_id], I get the parameter printed.  But when I visit the page, I get an error saying: unknown attribute: chapter_id.